# What is better performance wise, 1 huge js and css file or multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, performance

Right now, I work on multiple css and js files but I combine them all together in 1 big file. I am not sure if this is the right way. For example my js file is about 200kb(Foundation + jQuery). This file is only loaded at the end of the body, so I am not sure what is the best way, I mean the file size won't get smaller anyway if I split them up.

Comment: But browser will make multiple requests if you have more files (profile it!). Also compression might be higher for longer file. However, if you change them individually then you will re-download everything. Did you think about CDNs?

Comment: Curious, of your codebase, how much if its size comes from libraries/frameworks/plugins?

Answer (score 1):

You should always combine your CSS and JS files into a single file per type as a general rule.

However, if you really want to play around with load optimization, you can try to take advantage of the amount of simultaneous downloads a browser can do at one time. If it can do 6 at a time, then you won't see any major performance hit, and you may even get a performance gain, for having up to 6 separate files so they can download in parallel.

I personally wouldn't count on the simultaneous downloads though. It is a better rule of thumb to just combine them.

You can always use [Googles PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to review your site for load optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You should always combine and minify CSS and JS files. The browser makes fewer a separate request for each file you have. That's a small hit, but if you have a lot of files, it adds up.

https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources
https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/reduce-http-requests

Task runners like Grunt and Gulp can help with this. You can set up a script to minify and combine (concat) your files all in one action.

Or your IDE might even have it built in, so that everytime you save, a new file is compiled.

Always make sure your JS is right before the closing body tag, unless you have a specific reason to put it higher on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for optimizing a website is firstly 
 1. To reduce the number of files to be loaded which reduces the number of browser requests,
 2. To use server cache, to removing the repetition of MySql queries or connections
 3. To use browser cache for the bigs javascript files
 4. [Synchronous and asynchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) or Ajax/Jquery